# Problem with graphics on 12.10

Tags: fglrx

I just installed 12.10 x86_64 to my new computer

My hardware specs are:
amd fx8120 cpu,
ati hd 7770,
msi 990 fxa

I'm facing the following error:

```
2012-11-17 18:19:04,393 WARNING: /sys/module/fglrx/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind fglrx driver
```

From :additional drivers" can not install the ati drivers.
From "system settings" "software sources" only the x.org server is working but with problems

Compiz works continuously and if I open for example a video the fun is running like crazy.
The mouse pointer goes slow.
The windows act strange (flashing, don't open, open slowly etc)
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [purging the driver](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection?action=show&redirect=X%2FTroubleshooting%2FFglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a_Need_to_purge_-fglrx) and reinstalling - for which you can find general information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedDrivers/ATI).